# Button onclick won't work for Javascript query

Tags: javascript, forms, button, onclick

Hi I wonder if anyone can see what I'm doing wrong,

I've got a button which opens an email with the results of a form,

I can make it work fine if I do it as a text link

```
<a href="javascript:doMailTo(' ');">Click here to email </a>
```

However I can't make the button work at all

```
<button onclick="doMailTo(' ');" value="toEmail">Send to Email</button>
```

I've been playing around with variations but I can't make it work!!

The link and the button can be right next to each other, and the text link works when the button doesn't!

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The Function itself is

```
<script>
function doMailTo(addr) {
    location.href = "mailto:" + addr + "?subject=Flight Itinerary&body=" +
          encodeURI(document.getElementById('p3').textContent);
}
 </script>
```

And it's located in the header

Comment: Can you post doMailTo function declaration ?

Comment: added it to the question, cheers

Comment: You may pass event object in your onclick function call. Then preventDefault it in your function defintion

Comment: Any console errors? Anything other scripts you have going? It seems like that should work.

Comment: Is the button inside a `<form>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons in a form default to `type="submit"` so when clicked, it tries to submit the form. Specify `type="button"`.

```
<button type="button" onclick="doMailTo(' ');" value="toEmail">Send to Email</button>
```

Comment: This is only an issue if the button is inside a form.

Comment: Yes. I thought it is. But reading the question again, I see it's not specified.

Comment: Yes the button is in a form, sorry that wasn't clear!! But this seems to have helped! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try for this on local system:

May This will work for you

```js
 


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bt1').click(function() {
        $('#fr1').attr('action',
                       'mailto:test@test.com?subject=' +
                       $('#tb1').val() + '&body=' + $('#tb2').val());
        $('#fr1').submit();
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="fr1">
    <input type="text" id="tb1" />
    <input type="text" id="tb2" />
    <input type="button" id="bt1" value="click" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He's using plain Javascript, not jQuery.